# EF Core - Can we do a dynamic number of OR operators with EF.Functions.Like?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.2

I have a simple query where the WHERE clause looks something like this:

```
where EF.Functions.Like(header.OrderNumber, numbers[0]) || EF.Functions.Like(header.CustomerPoNumber, numbers[0])
```

I'm specifically using `EF.Functions.Like`, because I want the users to be able to insert `%` as they need to. But I'm struggling to figure out how I can make this dynamic. As you can see from `numbers[0]`, I'm currently hard coding the first item to test. But really, I need to loop through those items and do an `OR` on each as I add them to the `WHERE` clause.

I had accomplished this before with `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`. I created a dynamic `WHERE` statement and use `.Contains`. But the problem with that was that `.Contains` forced the double wild card character when it created the query. I need to be able to let the users choose when to include it.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to build the "where" predicate dynamically.

It can be done using `Expressions`:

```
// We want to build dynamically something like:
// x => EF.Functions.Like(x.OrderNumber, v1) || EF.Functions.Like(x.OrderNumber, v2)...

var likeMethod = typeof(DbFunctionsExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(DbFunctionsExtensions.Like), new[] { typeof(DbFunctions), typeof(string), typeof(string) });
var entityProperty = typeof(Header).GetProperty(nameof(Header.OrderNumber), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

// EF.Functions.Like(x.OrderNumber, v1) || EF.Functions.Like(x.OrderNumber, v2)...
Expression likePredicate = null;

var efFunctionsInstance = Expression.Constant(EF.Functions);

// Will be the predicate paramter (the 'x' in x => EF.Functions.Like(x.OrderNumber, v1)...)
var lambdaParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Header));
foreach (var number in numbers)
{
    // EF.Functions.Like(x.OrderNumber, v1)
    //                                 |__|
    var numberValue = Expression.Constant(number);

    // EF.Functions.Like(x.OrderNumber, v1)
    //                  |_____________|
    var propertyAccess = Expression.Property(lambdaParam, entityProperty);

    // EF.Functions.Like(x.OrderNumber, v1)
    //|____________________________________|
    var likeMethodCall = Expression.Call(likeMethod, efFunctionsInstance, propertyAccess, numberValue);

    // Aggregating the current predicate with "OR" (||)
    likePredicate = likePredicate == null
                        ? (Expression)likeMethodCall
                        : Expression.OrElse(likePredicate, likeMethodCall);
}

// x => EF.Functions.Like(x.OrderNumber, v1) || EF.Functions.Like(x.OrderNumber, v2)...
var lambdaPredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Header, bool>>(likePredicate, lambdaParam);

var filteredQuery = query.Where(lambdaPredicate);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I'm trying this out, but I'm running into an issue on the likeMethod variable. It's throwing an `Ambiguous match found` error. Would you happen to know how to fix that? In the meantime, I'm working on it. Just wanted to see if you knew off the top of your head.

Comment: I was able to fix it based on the code from this repo: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10834. `GetMethod(nameof(DbFunctionsExtensions.Like), new[] { typeof(DbFunctions), typeof(string), typeof(string) });` Thanks again! This looks like it works perfectly.

Comment: I'm glad you found the fix. I was working without the EF package so I just took a look at the API reference. I will update the answer with your fix.